# Optimal time to post a question

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I have asked several questions. Sometimes the ratio of views to minutes posted is 2:1. But sometimes its the other way round and I could ask a question which only gets 20 views within the first hour. This question is directed at the moderators mainly as they have the most access to the stats and stuff, but:

> When is the best time to post a question? Or in other words, when are the most users logged on?

Can you also please supply the time in GMT time as well as others that you feel necessary to include

Comment: Ironic how his question has only received 2 views in half an hour...

Comment: @manchu thanks, that is helpful

Comment: If you have the impression that a really good puzzle (yours or someone else's) did not get the deserved attention after a while (a week or two?) , you can always award it a bounty. If it is a questions which has already an accepted answer, and you still want to promote, you may nominate in in the 3-monthly "best of" posts.

Comment: A query at http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/queries might be interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: These are just personal realizations and are given only for help purposes.

---

- Less number of people login at weekends for reasons unknown.
- Majority of people on Stack Exchange are from USA. So it would be better if you post the puzzle at 3 p.m. according to GMT (i.e. 11 a.m. in U.S. ).

Answer (score 1):

Even though I have answered this question but I want to emphasize on the fact that we should not look at the time while posting a question (maybe especially a puzzle) due to the following reasons:

- A puzzle is not considered nice only according to the number of votes but it is considered nice according to the number of votes per views. So, 5 votes in 20 views are far more better than 5 votes in 100 views. It doesn't matter in how much time you get those views.
- If your puzzle deserve the votes, then it will get the votes. Sooner or later, people will see it and upvote it.
- I have stated in my other answer that majority of people on Stack Exchange are from USA. It doesn't mean that you should post a question according to US timezone. There are many people from other countries too who would love to see a nice question in their free time.
- Even though I have stated that less number of people login at weekends, but I think it's somehow good for a nice puzzle. Because the weekends not only affect PSE but the whole SE. So, SE and PSE gets less number of question. So there is a high probability that a nice puzzle easily get enough number of votes to get to the Hot Network Questions and therefore gain some more deserved upvotes.

Comment: Regarding your first point, see [this script](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/421254) that finds questions with the best vote-to-view ratio.